# I can not see my board's IP after connecting it to my router

Tags: ssh

I have a nanopi-m1 board(something like RPI), and tried to use Ubuntu-Core with Qt-Embedded Image File, kernel:Linux-3.4.y , but after connecting my board via Ethernet cable to my router and trying to IP scan with Angry IP scanner, I can't see my board IP! When I do IP scan, my board Ethernet lights flashing fast but IP scanner can't find the board's IP!

I did it before successfully but now doesn't work!

Comment: It simply might not respond to ping or be on a different network. Have a look whenever your router doesn't have an overview of active clients. Also check your configuration for the Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking the `Physical Ports` Boxes as you can see in the below pic in my router settings:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onfz1.png)

http://uploadday.com/plugins/imageviewer/site/direct.php?s=4E9&/Screenshot_from_2017-09-27_15-07-48.png